# My React App Could Not Be Deployed To Netlify Due To The Error Below

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my react app to netlify but I was getting this notification error below, How can I fix this?

> You have a malformed package.json in your folder. This will most likely lead to a broken build when attempting to install your npm dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "button-component",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: We would likely need to see your package.json to help you fix this.

Comment: Using a site like [this JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/), this appears to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your `package.json`. Common issue is leaving a trailing comma.

Comment: Please, How do I validate ?

Comment: Using a online site like https://jsonlint.com/, The `package.json` looks valid. Have tried building the app locally using something like `npm run build`

Comment: I don't know what to do again

Comment: Try building locally then push changes and try a new clean build on Netlify